# FabricJS: add a custom path around the objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am working on a fabric design js app & i need a sticker die cut like effect with my design app like in the link
http://www.stickeryou.com/2/stickermaker/selectart
go to this link first add some text & images & change method to image die cut
[image]

my code is

```js
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('design-canvas');

jQuery('#add-text-btn').click(function() {
  var message = $('textarea#add-text-value').val();
           
            var new_text = new fabric.Text(message, { left: 100, top: 100, fontSize: 20 });
            canvas.add(new_text);
            canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(canvas.getObjects().length-1));      
        });
        
        // image manage
    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
    function handleImage(e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
                    scaleX: 0.2,
                    scaleY: 0.2
                })
                canvas.add(imgInstance);
            }
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
    // image manage
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="7" class="form-control" id="add-text-value">Your Text Here</textarea>
<button id="add-text-btn">ADD TEXT </button>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
<div style="background:#eee"><canvas id="design-canvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas></div>
```

i want something like that
Thanks in advance for help
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create your sticker effect by incrementally drawing an increasing white shadow around your image.

[image]

1. Create 2 in-memory canvases using `document.createElement`
2. Draw an image to canvas#1.
3. Draw canvas#1 to canvas#2 with a 2px white shadow.
4. Draw canvas#2 to canvas#1.
5. Repeat steps#3-4 until you have the desired sticker effect.
6. Canvas#2 will have your image with your sticker effect.

You can then create a `fabric.Image` using canvas#2 as your image source. (*Yes...a canvas can be an image source for a fabric.Image.*)

**Here is example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('design-canvas');

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/owl1.png";
function start(){
  var stickerCanvas=stickerEffect(img,12);
  var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(stickerCanvas,{})
  canvas.add(imgInstance);
}

function stickerEffect(img,grow){
  var canvas1=document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx1=canvas1.getContext("2d");
  var canvas2=document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx2=canvas2.getContext("2d");
  canvas1.width=canvas2.width=img.width+grow*2;
  canvas1.height=canvas2.height=img.height+grow*2;
  ctx1.drawImage(img,grow,grow);
  ctx2.shadowColor='white';
  ctx2.shadowBlur=2;
  for(var i=0;i<grow;i++){
    ctx2.drawImage(canvas1,0,0);
    ctx1.drawImage(canvas2,0,0);
  }
  ctx2.shadowColor='rgba(0,0,0,0)';   
  ctx2.drawImage(img,grow,grow);
  return(canvas2);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:navy; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="design-canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks for help, but i want this around all objects like all images & text

Comment: If you add text with `fillText` then this same technique will "stickerize" both the image and the text. ;-)